# loopback ethernet interface how?

Tags: ethernet

I have a port called enps0f1  and I want that incoming data are looped back:

- I hope you understand this
- I use just one Ethernet cable.
- I use Ubuntu

maybe something like: `loopback enps0f1`
haha this would be to easy

```
    TEST-DEVICE --> enps0f1  ------------
                                        |
    TEST-DEVICE <--  enps0f1-------------
```

The TEST-DEVICE is a selfmade board

Comment: Looped connections in Ethernet might get immediately rejected from an hardware perspective (shutting down the port...), this is a protection measure (some routers will even power off completely if you do this)

If I read correctly, you have a single port and you want to inspect the output, is that correct?

Comment: hi, thank you . The test device is just a selfmade device. yes I want to use this one port ( one ethernet cable)